# Local display using Xming-Putty

Tags: ssh, xorg, putty, xming

I've been struggling with Xming and putty for a while and I can't make it work; 
I enabled X11 forwarding in putty, updated xauth list on the client side with the xauth list of the server side.

Currently I can run xclock from the client machine on the server machine when the DISPLAY is set to :0.0 (it shows xclock on the server machine), but I can't run it locally on the client machine; in other words, xming window doesn't pop up at all.

I already changed the DISPLAY to localhost:0.0, myip:0.0, and none has worked.
When I run xclock (when display is set to myip:0.0) it starts (I don't get "can't find Display" error) but still xming doesn't show anything.

In my `sshd_config` I have the following lines:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11Displayoffset 10 
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Comment: StackOverflow is supposed to be for programming questions. You should get better answers if you ask your question on SuperUser.com.

Comment: According to [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1246330/361600), offsetting the `X11UseLocalhost` to be `no` may help.