# How to open wcm Commander in os x?

Tags: macos

I installed wcm commander via brew in os x , however when i try to open it from terminal (wcm) i get the following error : **Error: can`t open X display (XOpenDisplay)** , is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi

Answer (score 1):

It looks like XQuartz is not installed on your Mac.

Try to do the following, according to the instructions given [here](https://github.com/corporateshark/WCMCommander/issues/5#issuecomment-54562762):

1. Download and install XQuartz: http://xquartz.macosforge.org
2. Reboot your Mac to make the X Server active

And to fix the **Clipboard** (Ctrl-C, CMD-C) issue, after running WCM, go to the system menu:

`X11 -> Preferences... -> Input -> un-tick "Enable key equivalents under X11"`

Hope this helps.