# clamtk Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display

Tags: linux, ssh, xquartz

I'm currently trying to run clamtk on a ssh connection.  From reading up on this I need to enable Xforwarding so I tried the following.

1. On an apple Mac I downloaded XQuartz.  There I ssh into my server doing `ssh -Y user@server`.  I'm able to login.  On the command line I run:

   clamtk

and I get this error:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:  at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Gtk2.pm line 168.
```

I also tried:
`ssh -X user@server` from XQuartz.  I get the same error.

EDIT: I went to the link on the comments and tried this from that answer:
1. Went to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and set `X11Forwarding yes`
2. I set `export DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:10.0"`
Neither of these worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "cannot open display" error when opening an X program after ssh'ing with X11 forwarding enabled?](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi)

Comment: Just tired all solutions on the thread you gave me, none worked @harrymc

Comment: use clamscan command instead

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this means the program has an GUI (Such as skype or wireshark do) and it cant display on a terminal.

Comment: Clamtk is specific for ClamAV on shell thou.  @Ecstasy

Comment: You mean GUI, not API.

Comment: I do.  Let me fix that lmao